# How to override autobean enconder and decode for Dates

Tags: gwt, date, autobean

The thing i want to do is to add a custom encoder/decoder using ISO 
8601. 
I think i can do that creating a custom version of GWT build but this 
is not convenient... 
Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: What is the use case of adding a castom encoder?

Comment: @Andrejs I need to preserve TimeZone info on the serialization. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=398